# I am using the input type="date" in my form and it shows mm/dd/yyyy instead of a date like 10/01/1992.

Tags: php, html, date

My code is as follows :

```
    <form > 
    <input type="date" value="<?php $row['DOB']; ?>" name="dob">
    </form>
```

the datatype of column DOB is date and when i want to view or edit the date is shows only dd-mm-yyyy instead of that date from database

Comment: well there you go, something broke

Comment: there is also not enough code to support this question.

Comment: You'll need to verify that `$row['DOB'];` actually holds a valid date. `var_dump($row['DOB']);` is a place to begin. Or perhaps you're not even fetching the value - there are quite a few unknowns. Check the variable, that the query successfully executes and fetches data.

Comment: Assuming your `DOB` row is a `datetime` or a `timestamp`, the echoed value will be something like `2017-01-01 12:34:56` which is not valid for a input date field. Use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['DOB']))` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure:

1. that $row['DOB'] actually has the date value (as Qirel already suggested)
2. that $row['DOB'] value is in the format: 2017-02-27 (NOT: 02/27/2017)

You can verify that the following code does NOT work (actually, this is browser-specific -- it does NOT work in Chrome, but it works in Firefox and maybe some other web browsers):

```
<form > 
  <input type="date" value="02/27/2017" name="dob">
</form>
```

But the code below works:

```
<form > 
  <input type="date" value="2017-02-27" name="dob">
</form>
```